# jQuery Dragging vs Swiping Gesture Logic On iPhone/iPad/Touch Screens

Tags: jquery, ipad, swipe, jquery-ui-draggable

This is a real pickle.

Basically I want some logic that determines this:

If the user starts a swipe gesture but does not complete the threshold distance in a certain amount of time (1 sec.) then a drag gesture begins instead, and the swipe gesture is cancled.

Is this possible...

And should I try and customize one of the swipe plug-ins...

Also what is the standard for touch plug-ins right now (jQuery Mobile, various plug-ins or a map of touch events to jQuery events...

Sorry I am not smart enough to work this out :(

Answer (score 0):

So I got a little further on this problem.

I altered a swipe script to add both a distance threshold and a time threshold.

So to perform a swipe you have to touchmove over 150px and it has to be under 600ms in time.

The logic fires after the touchend/ mouseup event only.

The drag will still begin no matter what but it works alot smoother with new script.

The touch events are mapped to mouse events with this - [jquery.ui.touch.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/downloads/list)

Here is the swipe script:

```
    (function($) {

$.fn.swipe = function(settings) {

var config = {

    left: function() { },
    right: function() { },
    preventDefault: true

};

if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

this.each(function() {

    var startX;
    var currentX;
    var startTime = false;  
    var isMoving = false;

    function onTouchStart(e) {

        if (!isMoving && e.touches.length > 0) {

            if(config.preventDefault) {

                e.preventDefault();

            }

            startTime = new Date().getTime();

            startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
            currentX = startX;
            isMoving = true;

            this.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);

        }

    } 

    function onTouchMove(e) {

        if(config.preventDefault) {

            e.preventDefault();

        }

        if (isMoving) {

            currentX = e.touches[0].pageX;

        }

    }        

    function onTouchEnd() {

        this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);

        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        var time = endTime - startTime;

        var endX = currentX;
        var distanceX = endX - startX;

        if(Math.abs(distanceX) > 150 && time < 600) {

            if(distanceX < 0) {

                config.left();

            }

            else {

                config.right();

            }

            reset();

        }

        else {      

            reset();
        }
    }

    function reset() {

        startX = null;
        currentX = null;
        startDate = false;
        isMoving = false;

    }               

    this.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
    this.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);

});

return this;

};

})(jQuery);
```

Here is how to use it on the page:

```
<script>$(document).swipe({ right:function(){ $('#previous').click(); }, left:function(){$('#next').click(); } });</script>
```